# How do I write a loop to run and save outputs from a glm with multiple predictors

Tags: r, loops, glm

I am trying to create a function in r that will run a glm on a number of different columns of data in one matrix using predictors from a second matrix and then write the results matrix to a csv file. 
I have managed to do this for a single predictor glm using:

```
X<- matrix(sample(10,100,T),10)
colnames(X)<- c("f5", "f10", "f15","f20","f25","f30", "f35", "f40", "f45","f50") # The matrix with the dependant variables
Y<- matrix(runif(10, min=1, max= 50)) #The matrix with the predictor

M<-matrix(nrow=dim(X)[2],ncol=9) #the matrix to store the output in
colnames(M)< c("Species","intercept","slope","pval.I","pval.B","Disp","Dev.Null","Dev.res","Dev.expl") #the headings of the output file names  for species
ns<-colnames(X)

for (k in 1:dim(X)[2]){
  glm1<-glm(X[,k]~Y,family=poisson) #calculate the glm 
  print(g1<-summary(glm1)) #print the output in the file # filling the rows in the results table
M[k,1]<-ns[k] #store the name
M[k,c(2:3)]<-coef(glm1) # store the coefficients
M[k,c(4:5)]<-t(g1$coefficients[c(1:2),4]   )
M[k,6]<-g1$dispersion # store the dispersion
M[k,7]<-g1$null.deviance #store the null deviance
M[k,8]<-g1$deviance #store the residual deviance
M[k,9]<-round((g1$null.deviance-g1$deviance)/g1$null.deviance,4) #caluclate the deviance explained
}

write.csv(M,paste("test.csv",sep=""),row.names=FALSE) #write the results matrix M to a csv file called test
```

This is great for a single predictor model, however I would like to run the analysis using multiple predictors so that:

```
X<- matrix(sample(10,100,T),10)
colnames(X)<- c("f5", "f10", "f15","f20","f25","f30", "f35", "f40", "f45","f50") #dependent
Y<- matrix(runif(50, min=1, max= 50), 10) #matrix with multiple predictors
colnames(Y)<- c("h1","h2","h3","h4","h5")
```

If I attempt to run the same code the error message I receive is

```
Error in M[k, c(2:3)] <- coef(glm1) : 
                number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

which I think is telling me that the M matrix I have set up for the results is not correct, however I am having difficulty trying to work out how the M matrix needs to be defined in order to correct this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Charlie

Comment: Since you are using a for-loop, the index and partially filled in values are in the workspace. Print `k` and examine the `glm1`-object and the `M`-object entries to see where the dimension mismatch is occurring.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors when I run the code that is offered. You must be doing something that you have not displayed.

Comment: The error message comes when I create the second Y matrix which has multiple variables and I attempt to run the above for-loop glm with this. If I print 'k' then '[1] 1' is returned. The 'M' - object is the same matrix which is incorrect for the new glm model. I guess my question really comes down to how to setup a matrix for the results of a glm with multiple predictors which the outputs of each glm can be written to.

Comment: `length(coef(glm1))  #[1] 6` and `str(M) #
 chr [1:10, 1:9]` so the error message makes complete sense.

Comment: How might I go about correcting this error?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at the problem. I have managed to work it through now accounting for the increased numbers of predictors by examining more closely the output of the new `summary(glm)`